# Parse title from citation

Tags: regex, google-sheets, bibliography

I am parsing citations imported into Google Sheets. The data looks like

```
9. Chowen JA, de Fonseca FR, Alvarez E, Navarro M, Garcia-Segura LM, Blazquez E. Increased glucagon-like peptide-1 receptor expression in glia after mechanical lesion of the rat brain. Neuropeptides. 1999;33(3):212-5.
```

I want to extract the title, e.g.

> Increased glucagon-like peptide-1 receptor expression in glia after mechanical lesion of the rat brain.

When I try find and replace with `^.*.` only the last sentence (`1999;33(3):212-5.`) remains.

How do I delete characters up to the second period, and after the third?

Comment: How do you know that none of the authors in any subsequent citations will have no periods in their names? (i.e. you may need a more robust regex process than keeping only text between the 2nd & third full-stop.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume from your example that the authors initials will never have full-stops, and that they only contain commas, hyphens, and whitespaces, and that the record begins with a number followed by a full-stop, and additionally the list of authors ends with a full-stop. For example,

1. AB Name, AB Another Name. TITLE. Other stuff to be ignored
2. AB Smith, AB Jones-Smythe. TITLE. More stuff to ignore

Then you can use the regular expression

```
^[\d]+\.[\w\s,-]+\.([\w\s\d,-]+)\.
```

to capture the title between the second and third full-stop.

To implement this in Google Sheets, use

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^[\d]+\.[\w\s,-]+\.([\w\s,-]+)\.")
```

where A1 is the cell containing the string with the title.

EDIT:
What I did not explain in my first answer was that extracting the part you want is entirely equivalent to deleting the parts you don't want. REGEXEXTRACT with the right regual expression does this by matching the part of the string you want to extract and ignoring the rest.